# Expanding the values of an array when debugging in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

While debugging in XCode, is there a way to expand a collection or dictionary variable completely so that I can see the values of the individual properties?

For example, I have this object:

```
User:
name
email
phone
```

When I then have an array of two users that's being passed around when the application is running, and try to look into it in the debugger, I see this:

```
po users
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ [0] : <User: 0x7fa3ab597fd0>
  ▿ [1] : <User: 0x7fa3ab597bb0>


po debugPrint(users)
[MyApp.User, MyApp.User]

po users[0].name
"John"
```

How can I see the value of all the properties without having to dig in individually?

Comment: Thanks for the variety of answers. Will have to to try each one out.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [`CustomDebugStringConvertable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customdebugstringconvertible)

[Kilian Koeltzsch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38017918/3141234) is good, but I suggest a slight improvement:

Make your type conform to `CustomDebugStringConvertable` by implementing [`debugDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/customdebugstringconvertible/1540125-debugdescription):

```
extension User: CustomDebugStringConvertable{
    var debugDescription: String {
        return "Name: \(name)"
    }
}
```

Using `debugDescription` allows you to be more verbose for debugging purposes, whilst still reserving `description` for general use.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `description` property and provide your own string.

```
override var description: String {
    return String(format: "Name: %@, Email: %@, Phone: %@", name, email, phone)
    // Or simpler: return "Name: \(name), Email: \(email), Phone: \(phone)"
}
```

Edit: This solution is for the case when your class inherits from `NSObject`. If this is not the case, conform to `CustomStringConvertible`, as other solutions suggest.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work without conforming to `CustomStringConvertible`. I get the following: `error: property does not override any property from its superclass`.

Comment: @KilianKoeltzsch Yes, it works if the class inherits from `NSObject`, I thought this is the case here. Otherwise conforming to `CustomStringConvertible` is the more generic solution.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up. I rarely inherit from `NSObject`, I had no idea^^

Answer (score 1):

Implement `CustomStringConvertible` for your `User` object or value and they'll be printed as you want.

```
extension User: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "Name: \(name)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try using `p myArray` instead of `po myArray`.

If that doesn't work and you're already in the debugger and don't want to recompile with a new `description` of your object, you can do this instead:

`po myArray.map { "\($0.val1), \($0.val2)"}`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dump` instead of `debugPrint`.

From the Swift Standard Library Functions Reference:

> `dump(_:name:indent:maxDepth:maxItems:)`
>
> Dump an object's contents using its mirror to standard output.
>
> Declaration
>   `func dump<T>(_ x: T, name name: String? = default, indent indent: Int = default, maxDepth maxDepth: Int = default, maxItems maxItems: Int = default) -> T`